# How to deploy postgres with a new schema on kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have used this [link](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/using-kubernetes-deploy-postgresql) to deploy Postgres on Kubernetes.

below is the configmap :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
  POSTGRES_USER: postgresadmin
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin123
```

and deployment :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.4
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

I hope, a simple configuration at configmap or deployment yaml will help to create a new schema on postgres db.

Comment: Where do you have your schema file on local or a repository?

Comment: actually, I wanted to just create a schema `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS key;`
and store in configmap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Kubernetes postStart lifecycle hook to create your schema on given Postgres DB. Just update your deployment file with the lifecycle block.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: postgres
  name: postgres
spec:
  containers:
  - image: postgres:10.4
    name: postgres
    resources: {}
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/bash","-c","sleep 20 && PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql $POSTGRES_DB -U $POSTGRES_USER -c \'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS key;\'"]
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: postgres-config
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      name: data
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: data
    emptyDir: {}
status: {}
```

Comment: Trying this makes my Pod fail with the following error -> exited with 1: , message: "/var/run/postgresql:5432 - rejecting connections\n". Any ideas on fixing this?

Comment: Actually, it was my bad, I tried replacing `sleep 20` with `pg_isready` which doesn't seem to work, any idea why my approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

For your use-case, it is better to setup [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql) using Helm charts, for e.g.:

```
helm install stable/postgresql \
--set global.postgresql.postgresqlDatabase=postgresdb \
--set global.postgresql.postgresqlUsername=postgresadmin \
--set global.postgresql.postgresqlPassword=admin123 \
--set global.postgresql.servicePort=5432 \
--set initdbScripts."init\.sql"="CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS key;"
```

Answer (score 0):

The new DB schema can be create on the **running Pod**:

1. Find out the name of your Postges Pod: `kubectl get po`
2. Log into your Pod: `kubectl exec -it [Name-of-Pod] -- sh`
3. Copy your schema dump file to the Pod: `kubectl cp [Name-of-File] [Name-of-Pod]:[Name-of-File]`
4. Install schema with psql tool: `psql -U username dbname < [Name-of-File]`

Comment: just wanted to create a schema with config map or deployment file. In production, I won't be having access to do theses thing :(

Comment: In that case, you could create a config map containing your schema dump, mount that into the postgres Pod as a volume and tweak the postgres Pod's commands to first import the schema before starting the main process.